# How to Only Show Email Inbox through application on IPhone

Tags: iphone

I am working on one feature,which sends some information to server and server sends the email.
On the view I have to provide one button i.e Inbox which will open Native Inbox like we access photo library.

So is it doable?

Thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know No. You can send Emails with the `MessageUI.framework`. But access the email.app no. But try it with a Webservice. You send data and the server sends it immediately back. Not through email.

Comment: Thanks Sandro for reply. What I need is : Showing the Inbox folder of the email on IPhone once user clicks the UIButton on the view.

Comment: Yeah I meant that. As far as I know it's not possible... But why do you have to receive your answer in form of an Email? I suggest a webservice. ;-)

Comment: Let me specify more details ... 

I have one form on which User provides details regarding new account creation like user name,password,confirm password and click signup and this information is sent towards server and if everything is fine the server sends Email as confirmation.[ My worries is showing this inbox so that user can proceed with that email [ instead of closing app and opening native email.app ] and as I come to know it is not possible :( ] anyway Thanks Sandro !!!!!